# Clean and elegant view models in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

Once I found out MVVM I really liked it. The whole concept of binding, separating view from logic, testability, etc was very encouraging. It was a nice alternative for the messy, never-ending code behind. Than I learned there are commands that can be bound, which I also liked at first.

Having written a couple of controls using MVVM though I found out that my view models start to look more or less like code behind. Full of commands that did almost exactly what was previously done in code behind by event handlers.

Let me give you some examples.

There is a control with a button "Details" which opens another window.

**[approach 1]**
The first (and worst) thing you can do is call something like this in your command:

```
new DetailsWindow().ShowDialog();
```

That makes the view model strongly reference the presentation layer - ugly.

**[approach 2]**
Lets fix this problem using a weak reference and create something like IDialogService. We can inject a simple implementation that creates and opens the window. Now we got rid of the strong reference to the presentation layer and the command can look like this:

```
_dialogService.ShowDetailsWindow();
```

I still don't like this approach. To me it feels like the view model is not something that should decide whether to show a window or not. It should serve and handle data.

**[approach 3]** 
The elegant way to totally separate the view model from the presentation layer would be to inject the command itself. Than the view model would not be aware of presentation layer. It would only execute the injected action - no matter what it is.

**Question 1:**

Which approach would be best? I guess the number **3** is the winner.

**Question 2:**

Should this even be a part of the view model? I think it shouldn't as it seems to be the concern of the presentation layer. Maybe it's best to put it in a simple event handler in code behind?

The second example is more complex. In the same control we have a "Delete" button. It should open a dialog asking user for confirmation and if he says 'yes' it should delete something. In this case it makes more sense to put it in the view model as it really affects the data.

**Question 3**

This case is the most tricky for me. I can't use my favorite approach number **3**, because I have to display a dialog which is a presentation layer's job, but **also** I have to perform some logic depending the dialog's result - which on the other hand is **view model's job**. What is the best approach here?

Please bare in mind that I really don't want to use approaches **1** and **2**. I want the view model to be clean and unaware of anything related to the presentation layer - not even by weak references.

One thing that comes to my mind it to split the view model layer into two layers. Something like:

view --> presentation view model --> logic view model

- presentation view model

  - used as a control's context
  - contains *logic view model* as a public property for direct bindings
  - uses approach number **2** - now it's acceptable as the whole class is meant to perform presentation related actions
- logic view model

  - it is 'presentation free'
  - references specialized logic services
  - some commands could be bound directly to the view
  - some commands could be executed by the *presentation view model* which owns it

Maybe this is the right way to go?

**[EDIT]**

In response to the suggestions in comments about using a framework:

Using a framework will surely make it easier to handle windows, but it's not the solution to the problem. I don't want the 'logic view model' to handle windows at all, not even with a help of a framework. Referring to the approach I suggested at the end I would still put it in the 'presentation view model'

Comment: It's not a direct answer to a question, but you should look into using a MVVM framework (Caliburn.Micro, MVVM Light), 'cause they already have a lot of tedious work done for you, like dialogs or navigation. For example, Caliburn.Micro has `IWindowManager` interface, which can show a specified view model *as a regular or modal window*. That means you'd be only operating on view models.

Comment: Without the use of 3rd party frameworks, I would use something like `_navigationService.Show(SomeDialogViewModel)`, where `SomeDialogViewModel` contains all the data that dialog needs for display, and possibly some flag to identify that it's supposed to be displayed as a dialog. Then its the job of the `_navigationService` to determine how and where to display the view model

Comment: To echo what @Patryk said, I've found Caliburn.Micro works really well for this.  It resolves the appropriate Window or UserControl by convention, then allows you to inspect the ViewModel instance to determine its state after the dialog has closed.  You can roll your own implementation; the main challenge is resolving the correct View.  There are various ways to do this (conventions-based, attributes, method calls to register mappings, etc.)

Comment: The most elegant solution IMO is that when a command is executed a VM should just raise an event and forget about it and any subscriber should handle that event according to what it's supposed to do when the VM command is executed...

Answer (score 0):

Your ViewModel should just notify all the subscribers that the command was executed by firing a simple event. The View should subscribe to that event and handle the event by displaying a new Window...

ViewModel:

```
public event EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs<string>> DisplayDetailsNotice;

private DelegateCommand displayDetailsCommand;
public DelegateCommand DisplayDetailsCommand
{
    get { return displayDetailsCommand ?? (displayDetailsCommand = new DelegateCommand(DisplayDetails)); }
    }

public void DisplayDetailsWindow()
{
    //
    Notify(DisplayDetailsNotice, new NotificationEventArgs<string("DisplayDetails"));
}
```

View (note that the VM is already the DataContext of the View):

```
private readonly MyViewModel mvm;

//Get reference to VM and subscribe to VM event(s) in Constructor

mvm = DataContext as MyViewModel;
if (mvm == null) return;
mvm.DisplayDetailsNotice += DisplayDetails;

private void DisplayDetails(object sender, NotificationEventArgs<string> e)
{
    DetailsWindow = new DetailsWindow { Owner = this };
    DetailsWindow.ShowDialog();
}
```

This way, when the command is executed the VM raises the event and the View which is subscribed to VM events handles the event by displaying the details windows using the `ShowDialog()` method. Since all the VM does is publish an event it remains agnostic of and decoupled from the View leaving the MVVM pattern intact. Since VM is already the DataContext of the View and the View binds to properties of the VM as it is obtaining a reference to the VM is also not breaking the MVVM pattern...

Note that this syntax is valid with Simple MVVM Toolkit MVVM framework. As suggested in comments you should start using an MVVM framework (my recommendations are Simple MVVM Toolkit or MVVM Light, Caliburn is too complex for no reason and no gain IMO) in order to avoid having to deal with the plumbing yourself...

Comment: I don't think this is a good approach. The view should not be dependent on view model (here it is because of the cast of the DataContext). This way you can't feed the view with another view model.

Comment: VM is already the DataContext of the View so why is it a problem?

Comment: The problem is that you can put different view model classes which behave differently in the view's DataContext - depending on situation. In your scenario it's impossible.

Comment: Why would that be impossible. How are you changing the DataContext of a View at run-time? Where ever you change DataContext of the View you can obtain the reference of the new VM from there and subscribe to its events... notifying the view via events is the standard way of communication between the VM and the V in MVVM which keeps the VM decoupled...

Comment: You cast the DataContext property which is an object to a certain view model class (MyViewModel). This DataContext property can be set multiple times in runtime by whatever owns the view, e.q. like this: {{myView.DataContext = new AnotherViewModelClass();}}. Ok it's possible to handle all possible view model classes in code behind, but definitely it's not elegant. :)

Comment: What would be the purpose of changing the VM of a View at run-time? View typically displays some data by databinding to properties in a VM. How is it elegant to have multiple VMs with same properties and what is the problem that this solves that could not be solved within a single VM?

Comment: I can't think of a better example right now, but lets assume we have a view which displays a timeline. It needs an object with a Name and a collection of dates (Dates). You could populate it with anything that has these 2 properties. I know this is a little far-fetched, but I think you should see the point.

Comment: Those 2 properties are variables so what advantage could possibly be gained by changing the DataContext of the View at run-time instead of simply changing the values of those two properties (which are already bound to the controls displaying them in the view) in the existing DataContext based on some logic? I have never seen a real-world example where changing the DataContext of a View at run-time was the only possible or even the most elegant solution to some problem...

Comment: @gisek If changing the data context does actually happen, the viewModel can always implement an interface that provides the appropriate event for the view to subscribe to. When the data context changes, the view simply unsubscribes from the current event, checks that the new object implements the appropriate interface and if so subscribes to the new event. If you are worried about the code being in the code behind then this logic could always be refactored into an attached behaviour.